# Tkinter GUI, add large .py file for a user. What if user does not have python?

Tags: python, tkinter

I worked at a GUI and made it into a executable.

But when I run the executable which should do:
os.system('python Test.py x)

It can't do this because the user doesn't have python installed and the command prompt doesn't understand the line: python Test.py

---

The way I might fix it is to make one big function in tkinter which has the entire Test.py code in it. This will costs me a lot of work to put all this code within a function / tkinter button.

Is there a simple way to do this? (I have over 15 functions and 3000+ lines of code)

Comment: Are you sure you made it into an *.exe? If you did you wouldn't need to run python *.py. Try looking at https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: Try `f"{sys.executable} Test.py"`.

Comment: @AlmogStern the GUI becomes an executable, but within the GUI I want to call a .py script

Comment: @acw1668 I don't understand exactly. Where should I use this line?

Comment: Use in `os.system(...)`, ie `os.system(f"{sys.executable} Test.py")`. Note that you need to import `os` module.

Comment: @acw1668 I also add an input to the .py file. So should it be: os.system(f"{sys.executable} Test.py " + filename) in that case? ---- Then just make that into a .exe file and the .exe file will understand how to run .py? How does it work?

Comment: `sys.executable` is just the fullpath name of the Python executabe running current script.