# I'm using os.system(python Test.py), can I show an error to the user?

Tags: python, tkinter

When the users click a button on the GUI,

the line: `os.system(python Test.py test_argument)` runs.

But when an argument is given that isn't working, the .py file won't complete. Is there anyway I can show the user of the GUI that this .py file didn't run to the end / didn't complete

Code:

```
import sys
import os
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox
#import tkinter as tk
import tkinter.ttk
from IPython import get_ipython
from tkinter import filedialog
import subprocess

# Run A TKinter Application Script

#Create Window
window=Tk()
window["bg"] = "gray"
window.title('SPS Automation App')
window.geometry('500x250')


def browse_files():
    global filename
    filename = filedialog.askopenfilename()
    filename = '\"' + filename + '\"'
    print(filename)
    label2 = Label(window)
    label2['text'] = 'Unknown'
    if len(str(filename)) > 3:  
        label2['text'] = filename
    else:
        label2['text'] = 'You didn\'t upload any file yet.'

    label2.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    
def run():
    #os.stat('python Test6.py ' + filename)
    os.system('python Test6.py ' + filename)
    label3 = Label(window)
    label3['text'] = 'Success!'
    label3.grid(column=3, row=2, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)
    
#def run2():
 #   os.system('python concatenateOBM.py)


Button1 = Button(window, text='Upload SPS', fg='black', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=browse_files)
Button1.grid(column=1, row=1, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

Button2 = Button(window, text='Create OBM', fg='green', bg='white', height = 2, width = 19, command=run)
Button2.grid(column=1, row=4, sticky=E, padx=5, pady=5)

window.mainloop()
```

The code works, but when I input a file that the .py file doesn't know how to work with, I can not see the error message.

Comment: Try putting that in quotes..  i.e . ```os.system("python Test.py test_argument")```

Comment: I have that. Sorry. - But it doesn't fix what I'm struggling with

Comment: What are you struggling with?   It isn't really clear in your post.  Please include relevant parts of your script/program.

Comment: @ewokx I didn't add the code because the code is working.  I will post it now so you have a better idea.

Comment: @ewokx So the problem is, sometimes the .py file that the GUI runs with an input file, isn't completing. (For example because the input file isn't right for the .py file. But the user can not see this. I want an error message to show up in the GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`exit_code = os.system("python Test.py test_argument")` returns the exit code, it is `0` if the process is successful, otherwise it is something else ...

simply checking for the `exit_code` to be `0` should suffice.

```py
exit_code = os.system('python Test6.py ' + filename)
if exit_code != 0:
    print("error occured")
```

this is okay for python failures, python will return `1` if it crashed due to a runtime Value error for example and `2` if it couldn't start, and `0` will only return if :

1. script ran to the end
2. script is terminated using `exit(0)`

**Edit:** for displaying error to the user, the error is sent over the `stderr` that you should capture, this is beyond the capabilities of `os.system` and you need to use the [subprocess](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) library.

```py
import subprocess
process = subprocess.run('python Test6.py ' + filename ,stderr=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True) # run the file
if process.returncode != 0: # check if error happened
    error = process.stderr.decode() # grab the error
    print(error) # print the error
```

Comment: For me it doesn't return 0 , 1 or 2. It just returns 'python Test6.py ' + filename?

Comment: It depends on how Test6.py exits.

Comment: @Akinnfenwa the exact exit code depends on the error, for example a segmentation fault will return a random code error, but it is guaranteed that a successful script will return `0`.

Comment: @Akinnfenwa okay, i'll add how to get the error ... but it is off topic.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Could you try it? I have tried it and I very sure that the script is succesful (I input the right file and get right output) but still the exit_code variable is not 0, it is just the string that I give the os.system

Comment: @Akinnfenwa could you post an example of `Test6.py`, it's hard to know why it doesn't return 0 by your description.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Its a very long file for work, I don't think I'm allowed to post it online. Could it not be that it doesn't output 0 because I'm running it within a GUI / Tkinter?

Comment: @Akinnfenwa the file might be finishing the work successfully, but it may not be exiting properly due to a bug in it when it is terminating, you should investigate it, anyway i added the code to grab the error from the child.

Comment: @AhmedAEK But if it isn't executing properly, it should give some other number right?When I print(exit_code) it just prints the string that I input to os.system()

Comment: @Akinnfenwa the operating system expects any program the terminates successfully to return `0`, if it is not returning `0` then it is signaling that a bug has occurred, whether this is the designer choice of how the program exits or an actual bug that occurred is up to the developer of `Test6.py`, but the only fact here is that it if it is not returning `0` then it is signaling `a bug has occured` which it shouldn't do if it did its work successfuly.

Comment: @AhmedAEK Your code that you added is working! (subprocess) and it gives me the error. Thankyou! That is what I was looking for

Comment: @Akinnfenwa consider marking the question as solved (the big true sign to the left of the answer).

Comment: @AhmedAEK Now that we talking, I have one more thing I struggle with. Maybe you know the answer, I posted it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74029816/tkinter-gui-add-large-py-file-for-a-user-what-if-user-does-not-have-python

Comment: @AhmedAEK, Anyway thankyou a lot and I will mark it as solved!